# How to create a release job in Jenkins which considers Jira tickets status

Tags: jenkins, release, jira-plugin

I would like to create a release job in Jenkins.
The thing is - I would like to have a conditional step which verifies that all related Jira tickets (by fix-version) are Closed.

I found plugins which updates the relevant tickets - but I just want to verify all of them are close... and if not - just fail the job.

Is there such plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a shell curl request to

```
https://${JIRA}/rest/api/2/issue/${ISSUE}/?fields=status
```

and parse status from it (you can manually open link in a browser and you will see the status).

Api call for getting the json for a specific issue:

```
curl -u login:pass -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://${JIRA}/rest/api/2/issue/${ISSUE}/?fields=status
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the filter saved in JIRA for listing the closed issues, then you can try the maxResults=0 on your GET, hope this link helps - https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-29903